# pop to the rootViewController within two modal view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iOS app.

The view hierarchy is like,

-- HomePageNavigationView

-- LoginNavigationView

-- UserProfileView

The root view controller of the appDelegate is the HomePageViewController

And in the viewWillAppear of the homepage, I check if there is a validate token.

If there is no validate token, then I present the Login Navigation View as modal view.

After the Login/SignUp process, the user profile is required to be edited. The UserProfileView is presented as modal view.

The other circumstance is, after opening the App, the validate token is found, but the user profile is not completed, so I have to present the user profile as modal view upon the Homepage.

So how to achieve this hierarchy, how can I dismiss view controller twice when I'm presenting userProfile view upon the login navigation view which is presented upon the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

So you can create block property for UserProfileViewController

```
@property(nonatomic,copy)void(^onDismissed)();
```

In LoginViewController:

```
UserProfileViewController *profileViewCtr = [[UserProfileViewController alloc] init];
profileViewCtr.onDismissed = ^{
   [self(YOUR_LOGIN_VIEWCTR) dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
};
```

and in UserProfileView:

```
[self(YOUR_PROFILE_VIEWCTR) dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    if (self.onDismissed) {
       self.onDismissed();
    }
 }];
```

**or more simply in UserProfileView**

```
[self(YOUR_PROFILE_VIEWCTR) dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
   [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion: nil];
 }];
```